# Why does computed "id" create this alleged ambiguity?

Tags: swift, identifiable

I have a pet peeve against the misuse of "id" to mean "ID." Unfortunately, the `Identifiable` protocol requires a hard-coded member called `id` for conformance; fortunately you can use a computed property for it. But doing so creates a perplexing complaint from the compiler:

```
struct BMessage: Codable, Identifiable
{
    var id: String  // Misspelling of "ID" required for Identifiable protocol
    {
        get
        {
            return ID // "Ambiguous use of ID"
        }
    }

    var ID: String = ""

...

    init()
    {
        ID = UUID().uuidString // "Ambiguous use of ID"
    }
...
}
```

To get around this, I have to put `self.ID` all over the place. Why?

Comment: I hesitate to even acknowledge this because it is such a horrible idea, but, technically, you can disambiguate between the two `ID` identifiers by replacing your `ID` references above with `self.ID`. That having been said, and your philosophical objections notwithstanding, it is a _really_ bad idea to use uppercase variable/property identifiers, even for acronyms. It really will become a source of great confusion as you progress through your Swift career. You really are better off accepting the universally accepted standard of starting property and variable identifiers with lowercase letters.

Comment: Thanks @Rob. As I noted above, adding "self" did fix it. I've been programming professionally on various platforms for almost 30 years (13 on iOS), and so far I've been able to maintain my lexicographical pickiness. I appreciate your reply though, and your warning is noted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Identifier` protocol declares an associated type named `ID`. Your struct's `ID` property name is causing a conflict and resulting in the ambiguous name error.

Property names should start with lowercase letters so simply using `id` instead of trying to use `ID` makes more sense any way. If you were trying to name the property as `ID` due to JSON parsing, you can use `CodingKeys` to map the `ID` JSON key to the `id` struct property.

Comment: Thanks. I object to making acronyms and abbreviations lower-cased, because they are all-caps in real language to prevent ambiguity. For example, an "id" is a theoretical psychological construct (along with "ego" and "superego"). It's also bad form to introduce extra verbiage as in "userID" simply to conform to the initial-lower-case convention. Thus my use of "ID."